# ora2pg could not open extension control file PostgreSQL/11/share/extension/oracle_fdw.control

Tags: postgresql, oracle, ora2pg

I m trying to migrate an oracle db to postgres using ora2pg, with schema already created in postgres, using COPY directive. The export seems done, but when trying to connect to postgres I get the following:

DBD::Pg::db do failed: ERROR:  could not open extension control file "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/11/share/extension/oracle_fdw.control": No such file or directory at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Ora2Pg.pm line 21943.                                                                                              FATAL: ERROR:  could not open extension control file "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/11/share/extension/oracle_fdw.control": No such file or directory                                                                                                                                             Aborting export...

I'm not using instaclient, I have a full installation of oracle 12 locally.

Edit: the file is not present in postgres installation, but from what I see Perl is trying to create it and fails.

Comment: Looks like you told ora2pg to use the ora_fce extension, but did not install the software on the database machine.

Comment: I have USE_ORAFCE set to 0 in ora2pg.conf

Answer (score 1):

I make comment out `FDW_SERVER  orcl` in *ora2pg.conf*, like this:

```
# FDW_SERVER    orcl
```

That helped!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).